# Angular 4 enable HTML5 validation

Tags: html, angular

I want to use HTML5 validation in Angular 4 rather than their form's based validation/reactive validation.  I want to keep the validation running in the browser.

It used to work in Angular 2, but since I've upgraded, I can't get even manually created forms without any angular directives to validate using HTML5.

For instance, this won't validate in the browser at all:

```
<form>
<h2>Phone Number Validation</h2>
<label for="phonenum">Phone Number (format: xxxx-xxx-xxxx):</label><br />
<input id="phonenum" type="tel" pattern="^\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{4}$" required>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Angular4 automatically adds a `novalidate` attribute to forms.

[image]

To override this, you can add the `ngNativeValidate` directive to the form.

```
<form ngNativeValidate>
<h2>Phone Number Validation</h2>
<label for="phonenum">Phone Number (format: xxxx-xxx-xxxx):</label><br />
<input id="phonenum" type="tel" pattern="^\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{4}$" required>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Unfortunately I do not see this reflected in the docs yet, but found it by looking at the source code:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_no_validate_directive.ts

It appears also adding `ngNoForm` to the form has the same effect as `ngNativeValidate` depending on your use-cases for needing to declare something as not a form for whatever reason.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work with pattern fields when I have form like `<form name="componentForm" ngNativeValidate #componentform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveComponent()" autocomplete="off">`

Comment: `ngNativeValidate` validate does not stop click handlers on submit buttons from being executed (FormsModule)

Answer (score 4):

use `ngNoForm` or `ngNativeValidate` in your form

```
<form ngNoForm/ngNativeValidate>
...
</form>
```