# angular2 form validation native alret

Tags: forms, angular, validation, angular2-forms

I made formGroup and formControl using formBuilder.

The code below is part of my code.

```
companyPhoneFormGroup: fb.group({
    companyPhone: fb.group({
        head: [ '', Validators.required ]
    })
})
```

I want to show my user native alret like this without write 'required' in html template. I can't found this way. please help me. thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIE5P.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are looking for **[`ngNativeValidate`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_no_validate_directive.ts)**

Just add that in your form tag:

```
<form [formGroup]="companyPhoneFormGroup" ngNativeValidate></form>
```

**Edit:** Forgot, that this though means that you need to set `required` in the input field though:

```
<input formControlName="head" required />
```

Comment: I do not think this works well, can I see the related documents?
And I did not use angular 4, I use angular 2.

Comment: Do you have to have "required" in html?

Comment: This is all I've seen. And now when I googled, I found that this would be a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43189364/angular-4-enable-html5-validation where also mentioned that there is nothing documented... Sorry about the dupe everyone!

Comment: Yes, you need to have `required`.

Comment: never mind. thanks your help.