# Angular validation with Required not working

Tags: angular, typescript

Simplest example ever not working.
I generated an Angular 4 application using the Angular CLI v1.0.6, changed the content of app.component.html to:

```
<form #form='ngForm' (ngSubmit)='submitForm(form.value)'>
  <input type='email'
  class='form-control' placeholder='E-mail' name='userEmail' ngModel required >
  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

And the content of app.component.ts to:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  submitForm(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

I expected the submit function to not be fired in case I didn't supply an email, but it does.
What did I miss?

P.S.: I have looked around for examples (e.g.: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-form-validation), but after many hours I am unable to find a solution, that's why I come to you. I know it is in my face, but somehow I can't see it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 4 enable HTML5 validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43189364/angular-4-enable-html5-validation)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Angular adds the `novalidate` attribute to your forms automatically when using the template driven approach. That's why you're not prevented from submitting.

You can use `form.valid` to see if the whole form is valid, and then create your own logic around how you want to handle it.

Comment: Thank you. That was, indeed, the problem. I inspected the html and it did have `novalidate` in there. I though they had simple angularjs template validation in Angular 2 and up. Even on the [angular.io docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#template1) they use html validation, though they omit the submission.

Answer (score 69):

@Fredrik answer is right.

Angular adds the `novalidate` attribute to your forms automatically when using the template driven approach. That's why you're not prevented from submitting.

But if you want browser validation then add `ngNativeValidate` attribute in your form.

```
  <form ngNativeValidate>
       <input type='text' name='projectName' [(ngModel)]='projectName' required >
       <input type='submit' value='submit' />
 <form>
```

Comment: you're a hero you know that!

Comment: @saurabhgupta Glad to help :)

Comment: Walking through a Pluarlsight Angular Basics and their method of validate works without the ngNativeValidate - but mine doesn't. This solved the issue of validation before the form sends data.

Answer (score 18):

The above answers are right, you just have to add `ngNativeValidate` to the form tag. I would like to add that if you want the submit button to not perform the `(click)` action when the form is not valid, use `form.checkValidity()`

```
<form ngNativeValidate #form >
   <input type="text" required/>
   <button name="submit"  type="submit" (click)="form.checkValidity()? login() : null">
          Sign In
   </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I found <ngFormId>.checkValidity() didn't exist for my code, I had to use <ngFormId>.valid instead. But otherwise this was exactly what I needed to keep the form from firing when validation failed.
(click)="form.valid ? login() : null"

Answer (score 3):

You missed `[ngModel]` attribute on your input element. Just add `[]` or `[()]` to ngModel attribute it will work as expected.

```
[] is used to give input to angular.
[()] is called as banana in box syntax and enables two way data binding for input elements.
```

You can do form validations either by HTML5 Validations or angular validations.

If you want HTML5 validations you can use `ngNativeValidate` as suggested by @RahulMishra

or

you can use angular form validations as suggested by @Fredrik Lundin

#### Demo

[HTML5 Validation](https://plnkr.co/edit/YIEs31QhUH0mopUUuiCf?p=preview)
[Angular validation](https://plnkr.co/edit/udBvYj?p=preview)

Comment: Nope, replacing my template with your plunker example does not work. Might be some weird interaction between plunker and angular.